# Chrome does not show ssl cert in trusted store even though its installed on Windows

Tags: google-chrome, openssl, certificate

I generated a self signed ssl certificate including the new `Subject Alternative Name` field. I've installed this certificate multiple times into `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` both from within Chrome and within windows.

The certificate shows it is installed properly in the windows certmgr, but it does not appear in the chrome certficate store and I get a `Not secure` warning on page load

> Certificate - missing
>   This site is missing a valid, trusted certificate (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).

If I try to install into a different certificate store such as `Other People` then Chrome registers it properly.

The issue may be because the certificate is for a dev domain I am forwarding from localhost, and a real (not self signed) certificate exists on the live site. I've tried flushing my dns.

However, when I load the site chrome does show my self signed cert, It just does not trust it as it is not in Chrome's Trusted store.

When I bring up the insecure cert the status shows `The issuer of this certificate could not be found.`

I'm on Windows 8.1 and Chrome 66.0.3359.139

Comment: You'll probably have to deal with CT too :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890552/referrer-policy-hide-the-referrer-of-self-signed-certificates

Comment: Turned out the issue was i was installing a generic cert with wildcards, used a more specific cert as a .pem file and it worked, even though it wasnt shown as one of the supported filetypes