# Referrer policy hide the referrer of self-signed certificates

Tags: windows, google-chrome, self-signed, referrer-policy, certificate-transparency

I can't seem to get the referrer on a 3rd party XHR request to a development server with a self-signed certificate.

After complying to chrome's use of SAN instead of CN and registering my self-signed localhost certificate, I got the green dot for this request in Dev Tools security panel, but I also get the following:

`This request does not comply with Chrome's Certificate Transparency policy.`

I've tried to use [Chrome Group Policies](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#CertificateTransparencyEnforcementDisabledForUrls) to disable it, but it did not work.

Have anyone else stumbled upon this issue? Any good know solutions for debugging 3rd party XHR requests?

Answer (score -3):

The current workaround (hopefully not a permanent solution) is just using **Mozilla FireFox** instead of **Google Chrome**.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a great answer for others who stumble on this question.

Comment: This is like telling someone to fix their broken sink, they should just use their other sink in the bathroom. Not helpful nor does it solve any problem.